# Multiple Minimum Spanning Trees in a Single Graph

Tags: python, graph, minimum-spanning-tree

I am looking for an algorithm that I am not sure how to define, but the idea is to have multiple disjoint minimum spanning Trees in a single Graph.

Consider this undirected Graph, where all nodes are every node is connected to every other node in the Graph. (Too Lazy to Draw, but imagine 9 vertexes exiting/entering every node)

[image: every node may be directed to every other node, at a cost based on direct distance]

A minimum spanning tree for this Graph may appear as follows:
[image: All nodes are connected through a min-span tree]

I am searching for an algorithm which can be fed with parameters such as: 
Maximum Vertexes pr. Node and Maximum Tree Span.

So that I for instance I tell the Algorithm: No Node may be directly connected to more than 2 other nodes, and no tree in the graph may consist of more than 3 vertexes (4 nodes) a result like this a solution.
[image: All nodes are connected to at least one other node, and the conditions as stated above the image are met]

It's eventually going to be written in Python 3.0, but for now I'm just looking for some input as to how I approach this.

Comment: A minimum spanning tree is a subset of the edges of a given graph. In your example, the graph has no edges; it is disconnected and therefore cannot have a spanning tree.

Comment: Every Node as they appear is connected to every other Node in the first image. I was hoping that was implicit as I was too lazy to draw 100 vertex connections.

Comment: Your edit now makes it clear, thanks.

Comment: In what sense will your forest be minimal? Simply removing edges from an existing spanning tree would give you *a* forest that satisfies your constraints. (Indeed, a trivial solution is the set of `n` single-node trees.)

Comment: If the size of the forest is to be bounded, do you want to minimize the total weight over all the trees, or the maximum weight of a single tree, or something else?

Comment: I would like to minimize the total weight over all the trees, but every node needs to be connected to at least one other node. So having n-single node trees is not an option.

Comment: OK, so the constraint `1 <= degree(n) < K` for some parameter `K` and each vertex `n` is what makes this non-trivial (since you can't necessarily just remove edges from an existing spanning tree).

Answer (score 1):

First, please note that this is not a trivial problem.  There are plenty of algorithms out there to find all minimal spanning trees -- but your inclusion of disjoint graphs turns this into more of a partitioning problem.

- This will involve dynamic programming to reduce your path explosion.
- Start with partitioning.  For each partition, collect the possible spanning trees.
- The product of these lists is your solution set for that partition.
- Write a function to return all spanning trees for a given set of nodes -- memoize the result, so you don't have to regenerate the list of trees every time you change a node number.

Now for the partitions.  You're getting into Grundy numbers here: all the possible ways to express a target value as the sum of possible integers.  This is a well-documented DP algorithm, easy to find on Stack Overflow with "algorithm Python ..."  For illustration, I'll work with only 4 nodes: `QWER`.
The possible partitions of 4 items, with at least 2 nodes in each partition, are

```
4
2 2
```

A critical question here is whether your nodes are interchangeable -- for instance, are

```
QW  ER
QE  WR
QR  WE
```

... distinct solutions for you?  If so, you now have four partitions to handle; if not, you have only two.

For each partition, generate all legal spanning trees.  The 2-node solutions are trivial; the 4-node solution includes configurations (using parameter nodes abcd):

a-b-c-d  (linear)
   a-b + c-a-d  (star, with a in the center)

Again, if your nodes are interchangeable, you have only two solutions.

[(ab, bc, cd), (ab, ac, ad)]

Finally, use `itertools.product` to form all combinations of your partition solutions.

Does that get you moving?

---

**Update per OP's comment**

Nodes and edges are not interchangeable.  Let's consider, then a 5-node system, QWERT.  This has 10 distinct partitions -- each must be a 3-2 split.

QW ERT    WE QRT
  QE WRT    WR QET
  QR WET    WT QER
  QT WER    ER QWT
  RT QWE    ET QWR

Each of these will follow the *same* configuration of solutions.  For illustration, consider the first: QW | ERT.  QW has only one spanner: the list of edges (one) `[(Q,W)]`.  ERT has three: `[(E,R), (R,T)], [(E,R), (E,T)], [(E,T), (R,T)]`.  Your collection of spanning trees is the `itertools.product` of these two lists.

Comment: Absolutely so just to make sure. I can't specify exactly what I'm working on, but I am looking at situations of up to 17 nodes, which would then give me a huge amount of partitions. And as to your question of wether QW == WQ. No. Those are unique partitions that since I there is an additional weight which I will also have to take into account apart from a simple vertex-weight. Thank you for your suggestions. Really useful!

Comment: My question was not about edges being bidirectional -- it was whether nodes are interchangeable.  However, your response includes that they are unique, which gives you a much larger problem.